# Split 2 string and join

Tags: java, android

I have 2 string which I want to join as per my requirements. Say I have

```
String sa = {"as,asd,asdf"};

  String qw = {"12,123,1234"};

  String[] separated = ItemSumm.split(",");

  String[] separateds = Itemumm.split(",");


     StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < separateds.length; i++)
        {
            if (separated.length == i + 1)
            {
                sb.append(separated[i] + "(" + separateds[i] + ")");
            } else
            {
                sb.append(separated[i] + "(" + separateds[i] + "),");
            }

        }
        deleteListItem.list_summ.setText(sb.toString());
```

> it gives as(12),asd(123),asdf(1234)

But problem is , it can be like

```
String sa = {"as,asdf"};

String qw = {"12,123,1234"};
```

So in this I want like

```
 as(12),asdf(123),1234
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
    String sa = {"as,asd"};    
        String qw = {"12,123,1234"};    
        String[] separated = ItemSumm.split(",");    
        String[] separateds = Itemumm.split(",");

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < separateds.length; i++) {
            if (separated.length == i + 1) {
                if(separated.length == i) {
                    sb.append(separateds[i] + "");
                } else {
                    sb.append(separated[i] + "(" + separateds[i] + ")");
                }
            } else {
                if(separated.length == i) {
                    sb.append("," + separateds[i]);
                } else {
                    sb.append(separated[i] + "(" + separateds[i] + "),");
                }
            }
        }
deleteListItem.list_summ.setText(sb.toString());
```

//      Answer :  as(12),asd(123),1234

Answer (score 0):

```
String sa = {"as,asd,asdf"};    
String qw = {"12,123,1234"};    
String[] separated = ItemSumm.split(",");    
String[] separateds = Itemumm.split(",");

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
// first loop through separated, starting with a comma
for (int i = 0; i < separated.length; i++) {
    sb.append(",").append(separated[i]).append("(").append(separateds[i]).append(")"));
}
// append remaining items in separateds
for (int i = separated.length; i < separateds.length; i++) {
    sb.append(",").append(separateds[i]);
}

deleteListItem.list_summ.setText(sb.toString().substring(1));  // remove starting comma
```

Answer (score 0):

if the lenghts of the strings are the sa, do the join

```
if (separated.length == i + 1 && (separated[i].lenght == separateds[i].lenght))
```